# Is there always a complete, orthogonal set of unitary matrices?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

The set of size-$n$ unitary matrices span $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ (this can be proven nicely using [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)).  If we select a maximal linear subset of unitary matrices, then we have a basis of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ consisting of $n^2$ unitary matrices.  My question is whether we can find a basis that satisfies the additional constraint of *orthogonality*.  That is:

> Does there exist a basis $\mathcal B$ of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ such that every $P \in \mathcal B$ is unitary (that is, $P^*P = I$) and for all distinct $P,Q \in \mathcal B$, we have $\langle P,Q \rangle = 0$?

Here, $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ refers to the [Frobenius (AKA Hilbert-Schmidt)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) inner product, namely $\langle P, Q \rangle = \operatorname{trace}(PQ^*)$.

When $n = 2$, the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) provide a convenient solution.  That is, we can take
$$
\mathcal B = \{I,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\} \subset \Bbb C^{2 \times 2}.
$$
We can use this to produce a solution whenever $n = 2^k$.  In particular, if we define $\sigma_0 = I$ for convenience, we can take
$$
\mathcal B = \{\sigma_{m_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes \sigma_{m_k} : 0 \leq m_j \leq 3\} \subset \Bbb C^{2^k \times 2^k}.
$$
Could we come up with a basis for any other $n$?  Could we do so for *every* $n$?

---

Some observations so far:

- Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mathcal B$ contains the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$. If $I$ is an element of the basis, it follows that the remaining matrices form a basis for the subspace of all trace-$0$ matrices.
- A commuting set of matrices spans at most an $n$-dimensional subset, so there must be elements of $\mathcal B$ that fail to commute

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought of this question while trying to answer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3155780/81360) on MSE

Comment: This may be useful: https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Unitary%20Bases.pdf

Comment: google on "unitary error basis"

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Excellent, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, consider the set of $n^2$ matrices generated by the shift $e_i \mapsto e_{i+1}$ and the diagonal matrix with entries $(1,\omega,\omega^2,\cdots,\omega^{n-1})$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $n$th root of unit.

Comment: Very elegant! Thank you

Comment: For what it's worth, these matrices are described in some detail [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices). They are sometimes called the "shift" and "clock" matrices.

Comment: Let $g,h$ be these matrices. Do you rather mean the set of those $n^2$ matrices of the form $\{g^kh^\ell\}$? The group $G_n$ generated by these two matrices is larger for $n\ge 2$. It is a (non-abelian for $n\ge 2$) nilpotent group order $n^3$. Indeed the commutator $z=hgh^{-1}g^{-1}$ is the scalar multiplication by $\omega$, and this group consists of the $n^3$ matrices of the form $g^kh^\ell z^m$.

Comment: Good point, indeed the formulation was wrong.